# Program to iterate through a string in haskell

Tags: haskell

i would like to iterate through a string in haskell by poping out each character just like a stack
till no more characters are left . a simple line of code to guide me through this is my bad code

```
name = "people"
answer = 
    if length name == 0
        then True
    else
     --(drop 1 name)
       answer
```

Comment: What is the type that you expect this function to have?  Although Haskell is very nice about inferring types for you, if you are nice to Haskell and tell it what type you are looking for, then the compiler sometimes offers helpful clues about what to do next.

Comment: I believe you should go through tutorials and search some practical programs on search engine. Your question is too broad to answer.

Comment: i am handling a task that involves iteration and popping out of characters till the list is empty.i would like to know mostly how to iterate over a list character by character

Comment: Do you expect the function to change the value of `name`?  Variable in Haskell are immutable so that is not possible.

Comment: `answer (firstCharacter:remainingCharacters) = answer remainingCharacters ; answer [] = ()`.  This function will traverse the list, taking no actions and returning a unit value (that is, `( )`).  It seems unlikely this is what you desire, but if it helps then great.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson. how would i then iterate through a list character by character

Comment: I just showed you. Perhaps instead of the how, ask the why.  Your goal is probably not to iterate over a list but to produce a new list, or count the length, or sum the values, or something else. Consider discussing the goal in addition to your attempt to solve it which involves iteration.

Comment: @lordken You don't iterate through it, you recurse over it, processing one character at a time. (And you almost never write `length` - instead, you examine the structure of your input.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is working code that gets as close as possible to your non-working code:

```
answer [] = True
answer (_:name) = answer name
```

For example, in ghci:

```
> answer "people"
True
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is an attempted transliteration of an imperative one:

```
name = "people"
answer = 
    if length name == 0
        then True
    else
     --(drop 1 name)    -- (*) NB
       answer
```

but Haskell is a functional language. Here (NB) you tried to write two *statements* in a row, but discovered it is impossible to do so in Haskell's **`if`** *expression*. There's no **`begin`** as they have in Scheme, no **`progn`** as they have in Lisp. Nor **`{ }`** braces as they have in C++... oh, wait, there are!

```
answer =                -- its inferred type:  Monad m => StateT [a] m Bool
  do { name <- get                   -- "get" the current value as name
     ; if length name == 0
         then    (return True)       -- base case
         else
            do {  put (drop 1 name)  -- "put" back the changed value
               ;  answer  }          -- and recurse 
     }
```

For the above to work, `import Control.Monad.Trans.State`. We use it as

```
~> runStateT answer name
(True,"")
it :: (Bool, [Char])
```

`True` is our answer, `""` is the final state of our *state*, the `name` that we passed in, which was getting its head characters "popped off" of it as requested, one by one, by the `drop 1` calls.

- (a digression:) "Monad" is just *something* that lets us use "magic words" – like **`get`**, **`put`** – peculiar to each specific type of "Monad", like the "state Monad" here; so we can have our own special language to use, peculiar to each specific type of task at hand. A *domain-specific* language, if you will. Well, actually, it is exactly what Monads are (*embedded* DSLs, at that).

  If we were only using **`get`**, then we'd have a more restricted monad, a "Reader" one. Or if we'd only used **`put`**, we'd have a "Writer" (Haskell can't use the same magic words to name different actions of different Monads, so it uses **`ask`** and **`tell`** instead, but that's just details).

We could've written it also as

```
answer name =           -- its inferred type:  Monad m => [a] -> m Bool
    if length name == 0              -- examine the received value
       then (return True)            -- base case
    else
       do { let x = drop 1 name      -- define the modified value
          ; answer x }               -- and pass it into the recursion
```

but then here the Monad is not being used *at all*, except for `return`ing! We haven't used any magic words, except for **`return`** (which is a general word that *every* monad has). So it's just the same as

```
answer name =           -- its inferred type:   [a] -> Bool
    if length name == 0
       then True
    else
       let x = drop 1 name 
       in answer x
```

because in functional programming the *returning* is implied – the last expression's value is what's "returned" from a function, i.e. it's what the function's value is, as a whole.

For such a simple task, this last, functional code is what's preferred. The **`let`** *expression* allows us to define a new value, first, and use it, later.

Re-measuring `length` over and over is of course an anti-pattern. In Haskell, there's *pattern-matching* to be used "for greater good" in such cases:

```
answer :: [a] -> Bool
answer name =  
    case name of
       []    -> True                 -- base case
       (_:x) -> answer x             -- recursive case
```

and *this* function we use just by calling it,

```
~> answer name
True
it :: Bool
```

The explicit `case` expression is more conveniently written with *clause* syntax, that you find in [the other answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48892104/849891), by [Daniel Wagner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/791604/daniel-wagner).

Now ask your real question, the one which talks about *what* you want to achieve, not *how* you think you need to go about it. But do it as a separate post, please.